# Git move from SVN: Where does git 2.6 store svn tracking branches?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have the task to move a project from SVN to Git and I followed the tutorial in https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git. The good point: it worked! The sad point, the tutorial seems to be out-dated when it comes to moving the remote refs for tags and branches.

The tutorial states, that they are stored in

`.git/refs/remotes/origin/tags/*`

however, in my svn clone, this directory is empty. They seem to be stored in

`.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags/*`

Same for branches, I expected them in

`.git/refs/remotes/`

but found them in

`.git/svn/refs/remotes/`

So, my question to you is now: is it safe to follow the tutorial but replace the corresponding paths with the one, I found?

**Edit 1:**

Assuming that it is indeed safe, I copied the references to their new destination. Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me:

```
$ git tag --list

$
```

Even though, the folder `.git/ref/tags/` is not empty. There I find tag-named folders with the following files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 delo 1049089   96 Nov 12 10:00 .rev_map.9585454d-0aa9-4b53-3453-ca0f383a6637
-rw-r--r-- 1 delo 1049089 247K Nov 12 10:00 index
-rw-r--r-- 1 delo 1049089   24 Nov 12 10:00 unhandled.log
```

Same for the branches. I think, this is not what it is supposed to be...

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty safe. Note that you could always create a backup before moving them.

Another approach is to use the steps from [this](http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/) tutorial.

Basically, you can do:

```
for tag in `git branch -r | grep "tags/" | sed 's/ tags\///'`; do
  git tag -a -m"Converting SVN tags" $tag refs/remotes/$tag
done
```

Comment: This tutorial seems to be out-dated as well. The `$tag` would be named `origin/tags/1.0.0` rather than `1.0.0`. However, it gave an hint how to fix that.

Comment: Yes, it's not to recent, but the concept is still valid. You can strip the origin/tag too, by doing: `sed 's/ origin\/tags\///'`

Comment: when you strip `origin/tags`, you must add it to `refs/remote/$tag` so it becomes: `ref/remote/origin/tags/$tag` otherwise you'll get `fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/MyTag' as a valid ref`. So I got the tags working now. Unfortunately, it is not so easy for branches, as there is no path `branches/`. The branches are located directly under `origin/`. Any ideas?

Comment: With the approach you will let git create the tag for you. The only needed things are to point it to the proper `ref/remotes/$tag` to properly identify the commit from the svn. In your case instead of `ref/remotes/$tag` I think you should use: `svn/ref/remotes/$tag`